# selenium.click() - block redirect

Tags: python, selenium, redirect, onclick

I want to figure out (in a general way) the target url of a clickable element without being redirected by the browser. Is this possible in Selenium?

Note, the clickable element generates the target url in a Javascript function. Hence, grabbing the href attribute of the element is not the solution for me.

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="redirect()">click me</a>

<script>
 function redirect(){
   randomPage = Math.round(Math.random()*10000).toString()
   window.location.replace("https://jsfiddle.net/random_page_"+randomPage);  
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Provide `HTML` for target element

Comment: @Andersson, what do you mean? An example would be nice?

Comment: Provide `HTML` + `JavaScript` code sample for that clickable element

Comment: @Andersson, see the example I generated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This `JS` function just redirects you to a random `URL` that ends with a number. I don't understand the point of this redirection, but seems that you can generate such `URL`s with your own function without using `redirect()`

Comment: @Andersson lets put my question different: after loading this example in selenium, can you get the url generated in javascript without actually opening the url / beign redirected?